# Log rotation (zipping/deleting) script in Solaris

Tags: bash, unix, solaris

Had same log rotation files in linux environment and there they work. In Solaris I have problems with running those scrips:

The main purpose of scripts is to delete all logs that are older than 30 days and zip all logs that are older than 5 days. `-not -name` is used because I want to operate only on rotated log files, for example `something.log.20181102` because .log files are current ones and I don't want to touch them.

```
#!/bin/bash

find ./logs -mindepth 1 -mtime +30 -type f -not -name "*.log" -delete
find ./logs -mtime +5 -not -name "*.log" -exec gzip {} \;
```

Problems occur with `-mindepth` and `-not` because it gives errors:

```
find: bad option -not
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
```

Based on search I have to use `-prune` somehow in the find, but I am not too sure how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Danek Duvall and with some searching I got it working:

```
find ./logs -mtime +30 -type f ! -name "*.log" -exec rm -f {} \;
find ./logs -mtime +5 ! -name "*.log" -exec gzip {} \;
```

It deletes all log files that are older than 30 days and then zips the ones that are older than 5 days.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the man page for `find(1)` on Linux (or `gfind(1)` on Solaris), you'll see

```
-not expr
    Same as ! expr, but not POSIX compliant.
```

So you should be able to replace `-not` with `!`, though you'll need to escape it from the shell, either with a backslash or with **single** quotes:

```
find ... \! -name "*.log" ...
```

Note that on Solaris, there's a command called `logadm` which is intended to help you take care of things like this, and may be worth investigating, unless you want to have the exact same behavior on both Solaris and Linux.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to fix -not. But still have problems with -mindepth

Comment: I don't think there's any equivalent with Solaris find. You don't say what version of Solaris you're using, but GNU find (available as `/usr/bin/gfind` on Solaris 11 and -- I think -- `/usr/sfw/bin/find` on Solaris 10) will have all the options you're looking for.

Comment: It's not clear to me what `-mindepth 1` is getting you here, though, since the only thing it weeds out is the top-level directory, which you're already eliminating with `-type f`.

Comment: But `-mindepth` is something you can reasonably implement with a separate command. Something like `find ... | grep / | xargs ...` should approximate it well for `-mindepth 1`, `find ... | grep "/.*/" | xargs ...` for `-mindepth 2`, etc.

Comment: There is actually no need to escape an isolated `!` character.